# Двойной слеш в URL. ЧПУ Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть Action в контроллере

```
public function actionCity($name)
{
   ///
}
```

Хочу чтобы при `site.ru/city/moscow` он пришел в этот Action и name было moscow. Как это сделать на `UrlManager` или .`htaccess`?

Answer (score 1):

- Вместо `controller` нужно указать название вашего контроллера, например если это `SiteController`, то должно быть `site`
- Вместо `action` нужно указать название вашего экшена, например если это `actionCity`, то должно быть `city`

```php
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        'city/<name:\w+>' => 'controller/action/',
    ],
],
```

Подбробнее в документации [Named Parameters](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#named-parameters)

Comment: Сработало, но есть еще проблема, когда URL имеет пробелы, это не сработает. На пример site.ru/city/moscow london или   site.ru/city/moscow&london  site.ru/city/scot's, site.ru/city/sankt-peter Как это исправит ?